# Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Future<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I am getting the following error for my weather app. How can I fix it?

Compiler message:
`lib/loadingscreen.dart:38:41:` Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Future'.

- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.

String weathericonlink = weatherdata['current']['condition']['icon'];

main file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'loadingscreen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: LoadingScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

the loadingscreen class is :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    String url;
    var weatherdata;
    url =
        'https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apikey}&q=51.509865,-0.118092';

    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      weatherdata = jsonDecode(data);
      print(weatherdata);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }

    double temp = weatherdata['current']['temp_c'];
    print('Temperature: $temp');

    return weatherdata;
  }

  String getCurrentWeatherIcon() {
    var weatherdata = getData();

    String weathericonlink = weatherdata['current']['condition']['icon'];
    weathericonlink = weathericonlink.substring(35, weathericonlink.length);
    weathericonlink = 'assets/weathericons/$weathericonlink';
    print('Weather icon link : $weathericonlink');

    return weathericonlink;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    //getCurrentWeatherIcon();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Hello'),
              Image(
                image: AssetImage('${getCurrentWeatherIcon()}'),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/weathericons/day/113.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do some [reading](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) on what a `Future` is and how to handle them.

`getData` returns a `Future`, not the map that you think it does. To obtain the map from the future, you have to handle the future with either `.then` or `async-await`.

With `await`:

```dart
Future<String> getCurrentWeatherIcon() async {
  var weatherdata = await getData();

  String weathericonlink = weatherdata['current']['condition']['icon'];
  weathericonlink = weathericonlink.substring(35, weathericonlink.length);
  weathericonlink = 'assets/weathericons/$weathericonlink';
  print('Weather icon link : $weathericonlink');
   
  return weathericonlink;
}
```

or `.then`:

```dart
Future<String> getCurrentWeatherIcon() {
  return getData().then((weatherdata) {
    String weathericonlink = weatherdata['current']['condition']['icon'];
    weathericonlink = weathericonlink.substring(35, weathericonlink.length);
    weathericonlink = 'assets/weathericons/$weathericonlink';
    print('Weather icon link : $weathericonlink');
    return weathericonlink;
  });
}
```

Now that your `getCurrentWeatherIcon` function is also a future, you have to use a `FutureBuilder` to show the data.

```dart
Future weatherIcon;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  weatherIcon = getCurrentWeatherIcon();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Hello'),
              FutureBuilder(
                future: weatherIcon,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if(!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                  return Image(
                    image: AssetImage(snapshot.data),
                  );
                }
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/weathericons/day/113.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```